# Multiple Result Set EF 6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have just started using VS 2013 and I would like to know whether the newly release entity   framework 6.0 designer in Visual Studio 2013 support multiple result set returned from a stored procedure?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried? Have you written the code to test it? Your question shows little research effort.

Answer (score 0):

The designer in VS2013 does not support importing stored procedures returning multiple resultsets to the model. You would have to manually modify the edmx - similarly to what you would have to do in the designer from VS2012.